# updateOne command in mongoose 5.5.11 every time I execute, I get response { "n": 0, "nModified": 0, "ok": 1 } ! what's going wrong?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I 'm trying to update a MongoDB document by mongoose model.updateOne command, But every time I execute the command, it responds {ok:1, n:0, nModified:0}

**Mongoose model :**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var measurepropsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  measureTitle: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  measureDescription: {
      type:String,
      required:false
  },
  measureSymbol: {
      type: String,
      required:false,
  }
});
var collectionName = 'measureParams'
mongoose.model('Mp', measurepropsSchema, collectionName);
```

**router :**

```
routerm.put('/editbyid/:id', ctrlMeasProps.edit);
```

**Route configuration :**

```
var routesMea = require('./api/routes/measures');
app.use('/mea', routesMea);
```

**and finally edit function :**

```
var Mp = mongoose.model('Mp');
module.exports.edit = function (req, res) {
    var measureParams = new Mp();
    console.log(req.body);
    try{
    measureParams.updateOne(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
            measureTitle: req.body.title,
            measureDescription: req.body.description,
            measureSymbol: req.body.symbol
        },
        (err, docu) => {
            console.log(measureParams);
            console.log(err);
            console.log('fin');
            if (err) 
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            return res.send(docu);
        }
    )
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

**I requested the below link,**

```
http://localhost:3000/mea/editbyid/5ce8e8555647bf5fb1b51803
```

**requested body is a JSON object like this :**

```
{
    "title": "sth",
    "description": "It`s sth",
    "symbol": "$0"
}
```

**and it responds :**

```
{
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 0,
    "ok": 1
}
```

**Here is collection "measureParams" data:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ce8e8375647bf5fb1b51802"), "measureTitle" : "AAAA", "measureDescription" : "It`s AAAA", "measureSymbol" : "%$" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ce8e8555647bf5fb1b51803"), "measureTitle" : "BBBB", "measureDescription" : "It`s BBBB", "measureSymbol" : "@@" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ce8f3b96bcf65fade7c5bcf"), "measureTitle" : "CCCC", "measureDescription" : "It`s CCCC", "measureSymbol" : "$$" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ce90bb3b78b6fbd4b9781ed"), "measureTitle" : "DDDD", "measureDescription" : "It`s DDDD", "measureSymbol" : "#$" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ce90ed9de934a056c00a383"), "measureSymbol" : "Or", "measureDescription" : "It`s EEEE", "measureTitle" : "EEEE", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ce912bc5a52000e009b6f2e"), "measureSymbol" : "Ol", "measureDescription" : "It`s FFFF", "measureTitle" : "FFFF", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ce937907d656012902702cb"), "measureTitle" : "GGGG", "measureDescription" : "It`s GGGG", "measureSymbol" : "QS", "__v" : 0 }
```

It should update collection by ObjectId `5ce8e8555647bf5fb1b51803` with new values mentioned in json body, but it does't.
I don't know what is the problem?
Do you have any idea?

Comment: can you try `... measureParams.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set: { measureTitle: req.body.title, measureDescription: req.body.description, measureSymbol: req.body.symbol }} ...` ?

Comment: Yes. I have already done before, but result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updateOne works with model name , try to update your edit function and schema file :

**update last line in schema file to this :**

```
 var Mp = module.exports = mongoose.model('Mp', measurepropsSchema, collectionName);
```

**And Edit function should look like this:**

```
var Mp = require('/path/to/Mp/schema/file');
module.exports.edit = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    try{
    Mp.updateOne(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
            measureTitle: req.body.title,
            measureDescription: req.body.description,
            measureSymbol: req.body.symbol
        },
        (err, docu) => {
           console.log(err);
           console.log('fin');
           if (err) 
               return res.status(500).send(err);
           return res.send(docu);
        }
     )
    }catch(e){
       console.log(e);
   }
};
```

Comment: @AliMohammadi please upvote if you like this solution.